# Google Chromecast receiver doesn't play simultaneous audio

Tags: android, audio, chromecast, simultaneous, receiver

I'm developing a Chromecast application (receiver, HTML5 and Javascript) which communicates with an Android app, all is fine, but I have a problem trying to play two "sounds" at a time in the receiver. 
It's a kind of game where I need to play a song at the beggining and play some sound effects during it.
Is this possible? And if it is anyone could help me to do it? I have tried it and it works nice in the browser but in the Chromecast only one of the "sound" is played, the song or the effect, never both.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one active Media Element in your DOM in chromecast. For what you want to do, however, you can use Web Audio APIs and accomplish the same for short audio files.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it following your advices, thank you very much